# Why am I getting KeyError here?

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, keyerror

I am trying to get the title of all the events in my calendar, so this is the code I took from the [Google website](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list#examples)

***My code:***

```
from Google import Create_Service
import datetime

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = "secret.json"
API_NAME = 'calendar'
API_VERSION='v3'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

sample = service.events()

page_token = None
while True:
  events = sample.list(calendarId='myemail@gmail.com', pageToken=page_token).execute()
  for event in events['items']:
    print(event['summary'])
  page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
  if not page_token:
    break
```

***The output I got:***

```
Holiday

Holiday

Holiday

Holiday

Holiday

Holiday

Holiday

Holiday

Holiday
```

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <module>
      3 events = sample.list(calendarId='myemail@gmail.com', pageToken=page_token).execute()
      4 for event in events['items']:
----> 5   print(event['summary'])
      6 page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
      7 if not page_token:

KeyError: 'summary'
```

It works fine for the first few events. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is telling you that the event retrieved doesn't have a `summary` key. I'm not sure what the `event` objects look like exactly, but you can avoid an error like this by checking if the key exists in the first place:

```
page_token = None
while True:
  events = sample.list(calendarId='myemail@gmail.com', pageToken=page_token).execute()
  for event in events['items']:
    # .get() returns None instead of throwing an error, 
    # or, as I've done in this case, returns a default variable: "No summary found!"
    summary = event.get("summary", "No summary found!")
    print(summary)
  page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
  if not page_token:
    break
```

Comment: This! Use `event.get('summary')` rather than `event['summary']` as it avoids a `KeyError` and can return a default value if the key doesn't exists (default value is `None` if not specified). It's likely that as you paginate across you eventually reach an event with an empty list of items, e.g. `{'items': []}`.